# Existence of known score but unknown exact code

Tags: discussion, answers

Consider the following the challenge:

> Write a program that accomplishes *X* task while maximizing the number of distinct characters in your source code. Removing any set of characters from the program should cause it to no longer accomplish *X* (e.g. it could error, halt, or just do something wrong).

Let's say the following answer was posted:

> ## Lenguage, \$A\$ bytes
>
> The first 256 bytes should range from `0x00` to `0xFF`. The remaining \$A-256\$ bytes can be anything.

If there exists a Lenguage program that can accomplish *X* in fewer bytes, then this answer becomes invalid, because one could remove characters from the end of the program to turn it into the shorter one, thus violating the rule that removing characters should stop the program from working.

In cases like this, where the validity of an answer depends on whether there is a golfed version, should it be posted?

---

By OP: I first asked that since we know Lenguage get a score of 256 even if there is a more golfed solution, should we submit an answer that not sure to satisfy the requirement. Therefore you may need to consider this part.

Comment: I am unsure what exactly your question is. Are you asking if one should post a valid answer with the same byte count as an invalid answer which was just found to be invalid?

Comment: It would possibly also be helpful to mention the specific challenge, as `It happened ...`.

Comment: @JonathanFrech If it's proved invalid the proof make a more correct answer, and in finite step it reach corret

Comment: So are you asking if the proof of invalidity itself constitutes as an answer? If so, I think the answer is yes, however I currently cannot find the meta consensus post.

Comment: Aha! Is your question related to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17403/194 and the request that language users put some effort into their answers?

Comment: @PeterTaylor What I met is a [tag:code-bowling]

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not know what you are asking. Therefore, I am voting to close as unclear. Please try to reword your question to make it more understandable, possibly adding concrete examples to the specific thing you would like to ask about.

Comment: It's hard for Lenguage to participate in a challenge, that's Lenguage's drawback, but why don't you just solve it in BF?

Comment: @EsolangingFruit I assume that OP intended to remove substrings rather than subsequences (pristine-programming); however it doesn't matter much in this context.

Comment: Regarding the "those bytes are gross" challenge, the tiebreaker is the length and reasonable people will golf it.

Comment: Programs can be golfed by subtracting some characters and adding others. This obviously won't work in Lenguage, but it could work in Python. So challenges like this would be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## Do not post an answer unless you know it to be valid

Answers are for providing solutions to the challenge. Do not create an answer unless you know that it provides a solution to the challenge.

That said, if you still think your (possibly invalid) solution might be of interest, you can post it as a comment or attach it to another answer.